# Fortran program giving a wrong output?

Tags: fortran

I'm new to Fortran, so forgive me if I'm doing something stupid in the following code:

```
program test2
    implicit none

    ! Variable declaration
    integer :: i, n
    real    :: s

    ! Initialization
    n = 1e+9
    s = 0.0

    do i=1,n
        s = s + real(i)
        s = s + sqrt(s)
    end do

    print *, s

end program test2
```

This small program outputs: `1.8014399E+16` and I expect it to give `1.0000000010000024E+18`. I use the GNU Fortran compiler on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: I usually run long simulations involving many matrices. Matrix multiplications, concatenations, reshaping, indexing, FFTs, random number generations, MAX, mean, powers, complex numbers, etc are the typical operations I use and I read that Modern Fortran comes with heavy support for matrix operations with super high speeds.

Comment: If you change `real ::s ` to `double precision :: s` do you get the answer you expect?

Comment: Wow, that is right. But I tried many other things like `kind = 16`, `real*16`, etc, but all didn't work, do you know why?

Comment: @francescalus -- Please elaborate your comment into an answer.

Comment: WRITE ( * , * )  'SIZEOF(s)=', SIZEOF(s)...  You may need REAL(i) to become DBLE(I) on the s = s + line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up using the following definition for the `double precision` variable `s`. This method has the advantage of being reusable and system independent. Thanks to @francescalus for the comment.

```
program test2
    implicit none

    ! Variable declaration
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(0.d0)
    integer  :: i, n
    real(dp) :: s

    ! Initialization
    n = 1e+9
    s = 0.0

    do i=1,n
        s = s + real(i)
        s = s + sqrt(s)
    end do

    print *, s

end program test2
```